# Wondering about while loop

Tags: c, while-loop

I started learning C 3 weeks ago, and while learning *while loops* I tried to build an addition program, basically you keep adding numbers it additions them and after 2nd number it gives you a subtotal for every addition, and if you press 0 to quit It gives you a final sum then quits.
Now I have one main, one additional question. The main question is, I had to use `sum = 0` before the while functions, if I use it after "the while" it gives me the number I entered as the result. Now I really wonder what is the idea behind it. When I write it like below does it equates "sum with 0"
for the start and changes the value as I enter another number, or there is some other idea behind it.

And the additional question is , why do I need to use 2 `getchar();` to make my program stay on the screen, why not one?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    float num;
    float sum;
    printf(" please enter a number +0 to start the program (0 to quit): \n");
    scanf(" %f", &num);

    sum =0; //THIS HERE**********************

    while (num  > 0)
    {   
        printf("please enter integer:\n");
        scanf("%f", &num);
        sum = sum + num;
        printf("current sum is = %f\n", sum);
    }
    printf("final sum is = %f\n", sum);
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I use it after the `while` it gives me the number I entered as the result.

This is because when you do this

```
while (num > 0) {
    sum = 0;
    ...
    sum = sum + num;
}
```

the value that has been accumulated by `sum` on prior iterations of the `while` loop gets erased each time the loop iterates, meaning that only the last value would be added to `sum` (and kept as the result of the additions).

> why do I need to use 2 `getchar();`

Because when `scanf` consumes the last number the end-user has entered, it reads everything up to, but not including, the `'\n'` character, which corresponds to the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. This `'\n'` character remains in the buffer, waiting to be consumed by your program. The first call of `getchar()` consumes that "lingering" `'\n'`, while the second one makes your program stay on screen until you press enter again.

Answer (score 5):

If you put `sum=0` inside the `while` loop it will be called each time the while loop loops.

This means when you reach `sum=sum+num`, you will actually be calculating `sum=0+num`.

You have two use two `getchar()` calls because the first one is sucking up an additional character that was not absorbed by your `scanf`. Probably this character is a newline, so you cannot see it. The second `getchar()` then keeps your terminal open because it is waiting for a character.

To figure out if my hypothesis is correct about the first `getchar()` you could try this:

```
char temp = getchar();
printf("%d",(int)temp); //Print out the character number from the first getchar
getchar(); //This keeps the window open
```

Answer (score 1):

`=` in most programming languages is different from the mathematical `=`. It does not mean that the two sides will permanently be equal to each other; rather, it means that the right-hand side should be computed and that the result should be *assigned* to the variable on the left-hand side. Later, another line might change the variable value to something else.

Thus, `sum = sum + num;` means that the current values of `sum` and and `num` are to be added, and the result is to be put back into `sum`. In order for this to work the way you wish, `sum` must be 0 the first time this line is executed; hence, you need `sum = 0;` somewhere. However, if this line is inside the loop, it is repeatedly executed, so that the result of the previous summation disappears and is replaced with `0` before each new number.